# Slow performance during Oracle import using GeoTools

Tags: shapefile, geotools, oracle-spatial

This is sample program which reading and shapefile and import into Oracle database. it also trying to rename the the_geom column to GEOMETRY column .

But this is taking time to insert into Oracle. It took me 45 min to insert 3000 rows with 8-9 columns. Is there any way we can better the performance?
I also tried to change the batch size to 100 from 1 but its still slow.

Below is the program for same:

```
public class WriteToDatabase2 {
    private static DataStore dataStore;

    public WriteToDatabase2(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException {
        dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
        if (dataStore != null && dataStore.getTypeNames() != null)
            System.out.println("Oracle connected");
    }

    public boolean isReady() {
        return dataStore != null;
    }

    private static void addFeatureandAttribute(SimpleFeatureIterator source, SimpleFeatureType schema,
            Map<String, String> changed, SimpleFeatureStore newMergedStore) throws IOException {
        List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<>();
        try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = source) {
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
                SimpleFeature f2 = retype(f, schema, changed);
                features.add(f2);
            }
        }
        newMergedStore.addFeatures(DataUtilities.collection(features));
    }

    public boolean writeFeatures(FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features, ShapefileDataStore shp) {
        if (dataStore == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Datastore can not be null when writing");
        }
        Map<String, String> changed = new HashMap<String, String>();
        SimpleFeatureType nSchema = changeDeafultGeomName(features.getSchema(), "GEOMETRY", changed);
        try {
            Transaction transaction = new DefaultTransaction("create");
            String typeName = shp.getTypeNames()[0].toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("shp.getTypeNames()[0]====" + shp.getTypeNames()[0]);
            if (!Arrays.asList(dataStore.getTypeNames()).contains(typeName)) {
                System.out.println("shp.getSchema()" + nSchema);
                dataStore.createSchema(nSchema);
            }
            SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);
            if (featureSource instanceof SimpleFeatureStore) {
                SimpleFeatureStore featureStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) featureSource;
                featureStore.setTransaction(transaction);
                try {
                    addFeatureandAttribute(featureSource.getFeatures().features(), nSchema, changed, featureStore);
                    transaction.commit();
                } catch (Exception problem) {
                    problem.printStackTrace();
                    transaction.rollback();
                } finally {
                    transaction.close();
                }
                dataStore.dispose();
                return true;
            } else {
                dataStore.dispose();
                System.err.println("Database not writable");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static SimpleFeatureType changeDeafultGeomName(SimpleFeatureType schema, String name,
            Map<String, String> changed) {
        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName(schema.getName());
        builder.setName(schema.getName());
        builder.setSuperType((SimpleFeatureType) schema.getSuper());
        for (AttributeDescriptor att : schema.getAttributeDescriptors()) {
            AttributeType type = att.getType();
            if (type instanceof GeometryType) {
                GeometryType geomType = (GeometryType) type;
                GeometryDescriptor geom = (GeometryDescriptor) att;
                GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = new GeometryDescriptorImpl(geomType, new NameImpl(name),
                        geom.getMinOccurs(), geom.getMaxOccurs(), geom.isNillable(), geom.getDefaultValue());
                changed.put(name, att.getLocalName());
                builder.add(geomDesc);
                builder.setDefaultGeometry(name);
            } else {
                builder.add(att);
                changed.put(att.getLocalName(), att.getLocalName());
            }
        }
        return builder.buildFeatureType();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File file;
        String path = "D:\\poc_new.shp";
        ShapefileDataStore shp = new ShapefileDataStore(new File(path).toURL());
        shp.setCharset(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.USER.key, "test");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.PASSWD.key, "test");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.HOST.key, "test");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.PORT.key, "1521");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, "/test");
        params.put(JDBCDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, "oracle");
        // create some random features and write them out;
        List<SimpleFeature> feats = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();

        SimpleFeatureIterator fi = shp.getFeatureSource().getFeatures().features();
        SimpleFeatureType sourceSchema = shp.getSchema();

        WriteToDatabase2 writer = new WriteToDatabase2(params);
        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> features = new ListFeatureCollection(sourceSchema, feats);
        writer.writeFeatures(features, shp);
    }

    public static SimpleFeature retype(SimpleFeature source, SimpleFeatureType schema, Map<String, String> changes)
            throws IllegalAttributeException {
        SimpleFeatureBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(schema);
        for (int i = 0; i < schema.getAttributeCount(); i++) {
            AttributeDescriptor attributeType = schema.getDescriptor(i);
            Object value = null;
            String name = changes.get(attributeType.getLocalName());
            if (source.getFeatureType().getDescriptor(name) != null) {
                value = source.getAttribute(name);
            }
            builder.set(attributeType.getLocalName(), value);
        }
        FeatureId id = source.getIdentifier();
        SimpleFeature retyped = builder.buildFeature(id.getID());
        retyped.getUserData().putAll(source.getUserData());
        return retyped;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would insert the data as is and then rename the column in the data base after,

Comment: @Ian Turton : I meant performance is not slow because of column rename, it is slow even without renaming . It slow in the JDBCDataStore.addFeature (write.write) part where even set insertbatchSize to 100, 200 but the performance is very bad.

Comment: that's probably to do with Oracle being slow - try without transactions

Comment: Yeah may be , I tried removing transaction but not much of help, but when I removed the spatial index which got created during schema create, it reduced the time from 30-35 min to 15 min atleast.

Comment: You should always remove indexes before big updates

Comment: The purpose of array insertion is to *reduce* the transaction overhead. Setting a commit interval of one ***increases*** overhead. Instead of 100 (or *shudder* 1) you should *increase* the count to 1000 or 2000 (though this might hit an internal memory choke if the server hasn't been optimized for load).

Comment: 15 minutes is still extremely slow to insert just 3000 rows. I would expect this to complete in less than a minute - 30s max: that is the sort of timing I get using `ogr2ogr` Either that database performs extremely badly, or the Geotools library you use is performing extremely badly.

Comment: You are right , it should be less than a minute. I don't want to use ogr2ogr as it does not give me much of control . I am still trying to improve the performance but does not have any luck yet. It is writer.write method which is very slow in ContentFeatureStore  addFeature

Comment: I even tried with 1000/500 but not much of luck it still coming more than 30 min.

Comment: Is there any chance to share the shapefiles for us to test the loading ?